# Facebook: How to control text preview in page post?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, preview

I use Facebook Asp.NET SDK.

I'm able to post on a facebook page programmatically using client.Post("/" + pageID + "/feed", parameters)
where parameters is my ExpandoObject with field setted like in the image preview below (link, i can't post any image).

I need to know how to control the placeholder i pointed out with ????
I can understand that it is a preview of my website text, but i wish to control and format correctly.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

[image preview](http://www.optimacase.it/documents/preview.png)

Comment: I can't find the answer in that post. I am able to choose the image, it's the text that facebook takes from my site that i want to set. It's not the title of the page, it takes starter text from body.

Comment: The answer there also has a link to more info about the OG protocol …